# Raman database of polymer spectra for analyses in R/python

Tags: spectroscopy, raman

Can anyone reccomend a raman database of polymer spectra that is open source or freely available? I'm analyzing spectra of a number of plastics and looking for reference spectra for identification.

The majority of available databases are stored in proprietary file formats that don't allow them to be pulled in to conventional scripting analyses in R/python, etc.

Thank you.

Comment: Format conversion...

Comment: That would be awesome, through the spectroscopy software platrforms that open the proprietary databases most often limits the ability to export in to something usable like .csv, .txt, etc.